# Does every closed curve admit a line that intersects it at only one point?

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry, plane-curves

Have a very basic question on closed plane curves, from [this Wikipedia math reference desk conversation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2023_August_8#Closed_plane_curve_questions), that I can't seem to come up with any results for. In particular:

If $C : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a closed curve (not necessarily simple), then does there necessarily exist a line $L$ such that $L$ intersects the image of $C$ at exactly one point?

If the question is rephrased to two intersections, then since simplicity is not required, space-filling curves serve as effective counterexamples. And, if the question is rephrased to two intersections plus simplicity, then it appears that the boundary of the [dragon curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve) (or some dragon-like curve) serves as a counterexample.

Comment: Consider a circle that encloses $C$

Comment: Makes sense, thank you very much!

Comment: Intersects the **image** of the  curve $C$ ?

Comment: Whoops, indeed; the _image_ of the curve. I will amend my question to fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $C(I)\times C(I)\to \mathbb R_{\ge0},\;\; (x,y)\to d(x,y)=|x-y|$ is continuous, moreover the domain is compact because its product of compact space ($C(I)$ is the image of compact set $[0,1]$ via the continuous map $C$). Then exists $\bar x,\bar y$ s.t. $d(\bar x,\bar y)$ is maximum, hence $C(I)$ is inside the circumference of centre $\bar x$ and ray $d(\bar x,\bar y)$.

[image]

Now we are done because we have just to take the line tangent to that circumference in $\bar y$.